# Correct way to add days

Tags: php, strtotime

I've tried to add 7 days to 2013-10-26 and got back 2013-11-01. But it have to be 2013-11-02. My old function was something like this:

```
public static function add($date, $years = 0, $months = 0, $days = 0)
{
    $date = explode('-', $date);
    return date(
        'Y-m-d', 
        mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[1] + $months, $date[2] + $days, $date[0] + $years)
    );
}
```

This was correct but too slow. I've made a new one that is more specialized:

```
public static function adddays($date, $days = 1)
{
    if ($days == 0) return $date;
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date) + 86400 * $days);
}
```

It works mostly correct. Not in this case. If you let calculate strtotime('2013-10-26') % 86400 then you will find out it is 10p.m. and for some reason it makes a difference.

I'm working with version 5.3.2.

---

Speed test:

Repeated 1000 runs for the 3 versions

```
DateTime : +7 day : strtotime

26ms : 43ms : 41ms
30ms : 44ms : 42ms
25ms : 42ms : 43ms
30ms : 48ms : 49ms
```

So more lines and a faster result. I choose DateTime of Amal.

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-10-26');
$days_to_add = 7;
$date->add(new DateInterval('P' . $days_to_add . 'D'));
$date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Thank you. But there is still the question why it wasn't working correctly from the beginning.

Comment: Summer/winter time was the underlying problem *sigh*

Comment: Why are you speed testing this? Are you doing some large data manipulation?

Answer (score 1):

The best method is to use `DateTime` class:

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-10-26');
$days_to_add = 7;
$date->add(new DateInterval('P' . $days_to_add . 'D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Output:

```
2013-11-02
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/56530)

Comment: @ortreum: What do you mean? Are you trying to subtract dates?

Comment: My function adddays must be able to add -n and n days. $datetime->{($days > 0) ? 'add' : 'sub'}(new DateInterval('P' . (abs($days + 0)) . 'D')); is slidely (15-20%) slower now. And with a buffer it calculates everything only once.

Comment: @ortreum: If you only care about speed, then use `strtotime()` and `gmdate()` as Glavic suggested. If not, it's best to use DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class to manipulate dates:

```php
function add($date, $years = 0, $months = 0, $days = 0)
{
    return date_create($date)->modify("$years year $months month $days day")->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/56529)**

---

> But there is still the question why it wasn't working correctly from the beginning.

Because you are using `date` function that is timezone and DST aware with combination with `strtotime` which isn't. For your example, you could use [`gmdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) that will always return time in UTC/GMT.

---

[Speed test different combinations](https://eval.in/56543), and you will see that fastest one is `gmdate+strtotime` combination. My run on 1M loops:

```
addDays_v1 needed 4.5433s
addDays_v2 needed 7.4234s
addDays_v3 needed 7.6924s
addDays_v4 needed 24.1624s
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
return date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 day",$date));
```

Comment: And where do I get $date from? Right strtotime(). It makes it slidely slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this-

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('7 days'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

Reff: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score -3):

Changing the last line to:

```
return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' 00:00:00 UTC') + 86400 * $days);
```

And everything is working fine. I've got my 2013-11-02.

Comment: @Glavić rules are rules but to answer right after posting .. in the same minute...

Comment: @Svetlio: I agree with you in this case, when this question was already answered 1000x times; but if this question was not asked on SO already, then this would be wanted behaviour. All I wanted to say, that questioner CAN be answerer ;)